# LastKnownLocation always returns null. how can i fix this?

Tags: java, android, get, nullpointerexception, launching-application

Location keeps returning null even after accessing my location via the virtual device.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_CODE);
}

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if(location != null){
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    //method to provide the cityName
    cityName = getCityName(longitude,latitude);
    getWeatherInfo(cityName);
}else{
    System.out.println("Location is null! ");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't get provider",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: That is expected, particularly if nothing on the device has requested location updates recently. You need to request location updates, then react if and when a location becomes available.

Comment: Did you test with the actual device?

Comment: @AbolfazlAbbasi yes i have